# Log-Log Graph, Curve Fit on Matlab

Tags: matlab

Im im trying to validate my engineering work using Matlab. I have a series of x and y data that I have plotted on a Log-Log Graph.

The result is a curve.

What I need to do is to apply a curve fit to this graph, and show what the equation of the fit is?

I have tried other answers on here and tried using polyfit and polyval but they aren't really doing what I need but what I lack is the forthwith understanding.

Kind regards

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `polyfit` to `logx` and `logy` instead of `x` and `y`, and then, to use the fitted result apply `polyval` to `log(x)` and use `exp()` on the result to get the actual fitted `y`:

```
logx = log(x);
logy = log(y);

fitp = polyfit(logx, logy, n);

newy = exp(polyval(fitp, log(newx)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Fitting in the log-space may be undesirable. Most likely you want to show the equation that best fits the data, not a transformation of the data. As a result, I would fit the linear data, then transform it for visualization as necessary. If that's acceptable, polyfit and polyval should work.

If you believe fitting in the log-space is important, I've used lsqcurvefit before, but this requires both the optimization toolbox and some idea of which function you'd like to fit (i.e. is your data best represented by 10^x or x^2?).  There's also the curve-fitting toolbox, which might be worth looking into if there are issues you could identify interactively with a GUI but not easily put into words. This provides a 'fit' function that could be useful too.